# Any 4 or 5 inch android phone that's easy to bypass activation?

Tags: activation

I'm looking for a large phone (4-5 inches) to be used like a small wifi tablet.

The problem is, that one's I've tried previous are pretty insistent on activation.  They'll ask multiple times everytime I reboot, which makes them very difficult to use as a mini-tablet.  Is there a way to tell which phones can have this easily turned off before I buy it?  Or is there a generally easy way to avoid that screen on all Android devices?

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic. As for activation, what activation are you talking about?

Comment: I'm referring to phone service activation.  Like Virgin Mobile, or ATT.  Not the Google account.

Comment: I have revised my question, to remove the word "recommend".

Comment: I voted to reopen, but I have only used retail unlocked devices for years... and I usually only get the prompt to "activate" the SIM once when you go through the initial setup wizard... My retail unlocked Moto and unlocked Nexus devices have never asked me to activate the service again. I think this is something built into a lot of carrier branded devices. I use a Nexus 5 and Moto G for light "developing" and hobbyist play toys, and they never ask me to activate them repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks.  My last few VirginM devices usually asked me about 5 times, and after failing, it lets me through to the desktop.  So from what it sounds like, I've just been unlucky, and most other devices won't be so much of a hassle?  I'm just asking because I don't know how to tell before I buy.  I suppose my question is more along the line of "How can I tell before I buy?"  Or is there a terminology for this that I can Google?

Comment: +1 on what @acejavelin said. "(carrier) Unlocked" devices shouldn't nag you for activation stuff, just optional Google account log-in on first setup.